# Using WHERE parameter in SQLSRV fetch array command

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I've got a piece of code here

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Registration, InGarage, BeingServiced, ReadyForCollection WHERE Registration = $numberPlate FROM SomeTable";
```

and the response I get is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 156 [code] => 156 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. ) )
```

but if I remove the

```
WHERE Registration = $numberPlate
```

part, it works fine? What do I have to use in place of the WHERE parameter?

UPDATE

New code is

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Registration, InGarage, BeingServiced, ReadyForCollection FROM SomeTable WHERE Registration = $numberPlate ";
```

UPDATE

Echo-ing code

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  while($row['InGarage'] = $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] = $unco and $row['ReadyForCollection'] = $unco) {
    echo "Vehicle is in Garage";
}
  while($row['InGarage'] = $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] = $comp and $row['ReadyForCollection'] = $unco) {
    echo "Vehicle is being serviced";
}
  while($row['InGarage'] = $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] = $comp and $row['ReadyForCollection'] = $comp) {
    echo "Vehicle is ready for collection";
}
```

}

Comment: This now seems to have turned into a very different question, and we'd need to know your intention and what all this $comp, $unco, etc. is all about. Perhaps you might want to start a new question for this? (Bear in mind, though, that the comparison operator in PHP is "==", not "=", which might be causing you some problems...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Registration, InGarage, BeingServiced, ReadyForCollection 
        FROM SomeTable WHERE Registration = '$numberPlate' ";
```

The `from` statement comes first followed by `where` statement.

Comment: @EdG:- What is the issue which you are facing with this code?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'ABCDEF'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'ABCDEF'. ) )

Comment: It thinks the variable is the column with your code? - the variable I entered is ABCDEF

Comment: @EdG:- Check the updated query. Updated my answer. You need to put the column in quotes `''`. Hope that helps :)

Comment: That worked. I've asked another question on the other answer. The result that I want to be echo'd now echo's constantly. Is there a way to make the echo only echo once? Do I need to use EndIf or something?

Comment: @EdG:- How are you echoing the result presently?

Comment: @EdG:- Try to change `=` inside your `while` loop with `==`

Comment: I don't want it to be a loop...! How can I make it run the query only once?

Comment: @EdG:-Then execute it without a `while` loop. Simply `$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)` Hope that helps :)

Comment: @EdG:- Also if that doesnt solve your problem then I would suggest you to post a new question as then it would attract new people and may be you get an idea. P.S. Do accept the answer if that helped. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You've got your FROM and your WHERE clauses the wrong way around:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Registration, InGarage, BeingServiced, ReadyForCollection FROM SomeTable WHERE Registration = $numberPlate ";
```

You should probably also be using [parameterised queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296201(v=sql.105).aspx). At the very least, if `Registration` is a VARCHAR type, you'll probably need quotes around $numberPlate:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Registration, InGarage, BeingServiced, ReadyForCollection FROM SomeTable WHERE Registration = '$numberPlate' ";
```

If $numberPlate comes from user entry, you should *definitely* use parameterised queries, otherwise you'll be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Registration, InGarage, BeingServiced, ReadyForCollection FROM SomeTable WHERE Registration = ?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array($numberPlate));
```

Comment: The quotes worked, but now it echo's my result constantly. Is there a way to make the echo only echo once?

Comment: Probably not without seeing the code that's doing the echoing.

Comment: Update in question added